# How to connect to a MySql server using SSH?

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, mysql-workbench

I need to connect to a MySQL server of my university. Below is the information about the server:

```
server: dasnr28.dasnr.okstate.edu

user: ****

password: ****

via: ssh (telnet via port 22)

html folder: /var/www/html
```

I have tried using the MySQL Workbench but its not working. Can someone please throw some light on this?

Comment: Define "not working". Skip the MySQL part for a minute - are you even able to SSH in successfully, for starters?

Comment: No, I am really new to this. I tried connecting to the server using the wizard provided in the SQL workbench but its saying connection unsuccessful. I guess I am doing something wrong. Can you please let me know how to get a successful connection using the above information?

Comment: You will probably want to get support from the university. What you are asking doesn't make a lot of sense without more context. Connecting to a database using ssh is probably not what you mean. The common port to use for mysql is 3306. That is the type of connection that Workbench would be trying to do. Otherwise, you would login to the server using ssh and then run mysql as a client into the local database.

Comment: MySQL Workbench, if I remember correctly, allows connection over SSH tunnel, so it makes a little bit of sense. Generally though you would have two sets of credentials. 1 to connect the SSH tunnel and 1 to connect to Mysql through that tunnel. Perhaps the credentials are the same between the SSH Tunnel (linux user) and the mysql user? Also, I would anticipate if they were using a tunnel they would also provide instructions to connect a client to Mysql through the tunnel, as that's not just knowledge you are born with.

Comment: OP, if you are on Windows, grab a copy of PuTTY and put in those credentials and server and see if you can get a terminal open on that server. Once on there use the `mysql -u <yourusername> -p` command to open the CLI mysql command line. Type the provided password and see if you can get into the database on that server. At least that will solve part of the troubleshooting/questions.